# html5 input type file browser differences

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

I have an issue with Firefox and IE11 that seems very strange.
I want to use input type=file to get a fileList, it works in chrome and Safari, the value returns the filename, but fileList is empty in FireFox and IE

here's the html, just put it in a file and open with a browser, or put it on a website and load the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>input file test</title>
<script>
function file1_click(){
"use strict";    
var f = document.getElementById('file1');
alert('value=' + f.value + '\nfiles=' + JSON.stringify(f.files) );
}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<input type="file" id="file1" onchange="file1_click();" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works just fine in Firefox, but it returns a native `fileList` object, and the `stringify` just returns different results, if you try to actually log the file with `console.log( f.files[0] )` you see that the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

f.files is an object. You can loop through it.

```
function file1_click(){
    "use strict";    
    var f = document.getElementById('file1');
    var filesArray = [];
    for(var i=0, len=f.files.length; i<len; i++) {
        filesArray.push(f.files[i]['name'])
    }
    alert('value=' + f.value + '\nfiles=' + JSON.stringify(filesArray) );
}
```

Additionally, you will need to specify the "multiple" property on your file input if you want more than one image.

```
<input type="file" id="file1" onchange="file1_click();" multiple />
```